# Show that on any uncountable set $X$, there is a metric on $X$ with respect to which $X$ is not separable

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> Show that on any uncountable set $X$, there is a metric on $X$ with respect to which $X$ is not separable

The definition we are using is $X$ is separable if $\exists E$ dense in $X$ and set $E$ is countable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the discrete metric. Then the only dense subset of $X$ is $X$ itself, which is not countable.